# activity/task based authorisation

Tags: c#, authorization, rhino, rhino-security

[Rhino security](https://github.com/ayende/rhino-security) seems to offer a nice way to perform task/activity based authorization. This is some example code:

```
bool isAllowed = authorizationService.IsAllowed(userXYZ, "/Messages/Change");
```

It checks whether userXYZ can perform activity 'Change' on resource 'Messages'. This is all great but I do not like the way the resource and activity is hard coded. Do you reckon there is a way to overcome this? Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean hardcoded? if it's a string...can't you build/retrieve the string from somewhere else?

Comment: Then you would have to maintain this. I guess one could use reflection  ...

Answer (score -1):

Why dont use web.configs? Check this nice article http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2008/09/29/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config.aspx

Comment: Also you can mix Rhino with appSettings, where you can define paths. Or you can use Rhino with any other file where would be stored settings.

Comment: This is not just for ASP.NET (MVC) pages ... besides this can get messy and I prefer everything to be stored in a proper db.

Comment: So why not make similar to article that I've posted? Create some xml file store there your settings (allow to, deny to, paths). read from there and decide allow user to do anything with that or not.

Comment: or this settings in db. where you want.